# Rails query gives different ordering during testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, minitest

My query works properly on the rails console and the web server where it returns a DESC order but fails during testing where it returns ASC order.

Below is the simplified model code.

```
class Room < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :room_members
 has_many :members, through: :room_members, source: :user

 def self.hot_rooms
  query = "SELECT r.*, rm,count
           FROM rooms r
           LEFT JOIN (SELECT room_id, count(room_id), max(id) as id
                      FROM room_members
                      GROUP BY room_id) rm
           ON r.id = rm.room_id
           WHERE r.is_started = true
           ORDER BY rm.count DESC, rm.id DESC
           LIMIT 12"
  self.find_by_sql(query)
 end
end
```

- Fixtures test data
- No errors except ordering
- PostgreSQL 9.6.1
- Rails 5.0.1
- Ruby 2.3.1p112

The problem is `rm.count DESC`.
The result of Room.recent_rooms is DESC on console and web server but *surprisingly* ASC when testing.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed.
The problem was caused by 'nil' count.(There was no nil on console)
psql count out nil instead of 0. And It assume nil as a big number I think.
So I modified the code, and I solved the problem.

1. wm.count > coalesce(wm.count,0) as count
2. rm.count DESC > count DESC